# How to view a FileUpload response body as an upload button when seen through Swagger UI

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, quarkus

I'm working on building a Quarkus REST API for uploading files and I'd like to use the Swagger UI while developing to have a tight feedback loop as I develop the site. However I'm struggling to get Swagger UI to format the file input elegantly.

I've tried to follow the [RESTEasy Reactive guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/resteasy-reactive#multipart) for instruction on how to accept a file as a response body for a route but I can't seem to get Swagger UI to display the input as anything but a large text field. Here is the Quarkus 2.14 example as seen through the Swagger UI.

[image: Quarkus example]

While developing APIs before I've grown familiar with a file upload prompt in the Swagger UI as shown [here in Swagger docs](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/file-upload/). The file upload prompt allows an end user to select any arbitrary file (binary or text) to upload. I'd expect I should be able to convey to Swagger UI that I'd like this field treated as a file instead of text.

Is this a bug or do I need some extra metadata to pick a more appropriate view for this API's inputs?

#### Details to reproduce

I'm using Quarkus 2.14 and am able to reproduce the issue simply using the example found in the Quarkus RESTEasy guide.

Quarkus Extensions:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
  <artifactId>quarkus-swagger-ui</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

RESTEasy Route:

```java
package com.me.example;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.PartType;
import org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.RestForm;
import org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.multipart.FileUpload;

@Path("/files")
@RequestScoped
public class ExampleResource {

    public static class Person {
        public String firstName;
        public String lastName;
    }

    @POST
    public void multipart(@RestForm String description,
            @RestForm("image") FileUpload file,
            @RestForm @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) Person person) {
        
    }

}
```

Rendered OpenAPI document:

```yaml
---
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: API
  version: 0.1.0-SNAPSHOT
paths:
  /files:
    post:
      tags:
      - Example Resource
      requestBody:
        content:
          application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                description:
                  type: string
                image:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/FileUpload'
                person:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/Person'
            encoding:
              person:
                contentType: application/json
      responses:
        "201":
          description: Created
components:
  schemas:
    FileUpload:
      type: object
    Person:
      type: object
      properties:
        firstName:
          type: string
        lastName:
          type: string
```

Comment: While playing around with the raw OpenAPI document I noticed that if I force the `type: string` and `format: binary` properties of the `image` field like in the [OpenAPI 3.0 docs](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/file-upload/) I can see the file picker show up in the [Swagger Editor](https://editor.swagger.io/). I've been unable to see this work through Quarkus code yet.

Comment: Can you post the exact code you're using, library versions, etc.?

Comment: @Helen Sure. I appended some of the details of my experiment to the original post.

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/28231#issuecomment-1259848398 The method should probably also be annotated with `@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)` so that it generates a `multipart/form-data` request instead of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Yes! A variation of that (single FileUpload instead of many) seems to do the trick.

Comment: @Helen: Thanks for your help! The suggestion is just what I needed to get unblocked in my particular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Helen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113116/helen) found a [relevant Quarkus issue](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/28231#issuecomment-1259848398) that helped identify a workaround to my issue. With some modifications I was able to get a single file to upload while maintaining the intuitive file picker interface in Swagger UI.

```java
package com.me.example;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.enums.SchemaType;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.media.Schema;
import org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.RestForm;
import org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.multipart.FileUpload;

@Path("/files")
@RequestScoped
public class ExampleResource {

    @Schema(type = SchemaType.STRING, format = "binary")
    public static class UploadItemSchema {

    }

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public void multipart(@RestForm("image") @Schema(implementation = UploadItemSchema.class) FileUpload file) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky.

Below is an example of Quarkus Reactive & Kotlin

```
import jakarta.ws.rs.Consumes
import jakarta.ws.rs.POST
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.enums.SchemaType
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.media.Schema
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.parameters.Parameter
import org.eclipse.microprofile.openapi.annotations.tags.Tag
import org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.RestForm
import org.jboss.resteasy.reactive.multipart.FileUpload
import java.io.File

@Tag(name = "Upload")
@Path("/fn/upload")
class FileUploadHandler {

    @Schema(type = SchemaType.STRING, format = "binary")
    internal class UploadItemSchema


    @POST
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    fun handleUploadRequest(
        @Schema(implementation = UploadItemSchema::class)
        @RestForm("file") file: FileUpload
    ): Map<String, Any> {
        val info = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
        info["fileName"] = file.fileName()
        info["filePath"] = file.filePath().toString()
        info["contentType"] = file.contentType()
        info["size"] = file.size()
        if (!file.uploadedFile().toFile().renameTo(File("logs/${file.fileName()}"))) {
            throw InternalError("Could not move uploaded file")
        }
        return info
    }
}
```

You need this `UploadItemSchema` class and `@Schema` annotation.
Also do not forget to set `@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)`

On this case proper openapi is generated:

```
  /fn/upload:
    post:
      tags:
      - Upload
      operationId: handleUploadRequest
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                file:
                  $ref: '#/components/schemas/UploadItemSchema'
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                additionalProperties: {}
```

Schema:

```
UploadItemSchema:
  format: binary
  type: string
```